# Rmarkdown: spacing between parragraph and image

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm writting a blog post in RStudio using Rmarkdown. The document will be rendered to HTML at the end.

But when rendering I'm not getting enough space between `p tag` and `img tag`.

I know I can insert a break line using 2 spaces, it works when separating text.  But it is not working for me when trying to set a break of text from an image.

**Rmarkdown in RStudio**:

```
Sin embargo, para lograr esto vas a tener que  
personalizar algunos registros de tu DNS en el Panel de Control de tu proveedor de hosting:
```

**Generates this HTML (Notice the br tag):**

```
<p>Sin embargo, para lograr esto vas a tener que<br />
personalizar algunos registros de tu DNS en el Panel de Control de tu proveedor de hosting:</p>
```

**But**: Inserting spacing between text and image does not generate a `br tag`.

````
Sin embargo, para lograr esto vas a tener que  
personalizar algunos registros de tu DNS en el Panel de Control de tu proveedor de hosting:  





```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="", out.width = '100%', fig.align='center'}
knitr::include_graphics("D:/omargonzalesdiaz/static/img/posts/sumo/custom_email_address.jpg")
```
````

**Generates**: No break line between text and image.

```
<p>Sin embargo, para lograr esto vas a tener que<br />
personalizar algunos registros de tu DNS en el Panel de Control de tu proveedor de hosting:</p>
<p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QwCRXhpZgAATU0Af//AkAtEbdSD+ft/kN97lEZ7DP6N5ABJgqd/0ElMi7K0HoMM8+/wD9RIlZfJ3sDB22mZ8Z9rVVGZbu1cIIloivXndDvtH" width="100%" style="display: block; margin: auto;" /></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to add html breaks to your script directly:

````
Sin embargo, para lograr esto vas a tener que  
personalizar algunos registros de tu DNS en el Panel de Control de tu proveedor de hosting:  
<br/><br/>

```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="", out.width = '100%', fig.align='center'}
knitr::include_graphics("D:/omargonzalesdiaz/static/img/posts/sumo/custom_email_address.jpg")
```
````

Comment: Works! Ty. But maybe is there a "correct" way to do it? Using CSS  maybe?